# Link Managed Package to Professional Edition

Tags: managed-package

I have unmanaged package that have few components (including apex/trigger) and it is working fine. For few customers I want to install the app in professional edition. but such org cannot contains apex/trigger unless it is from certified managed package.
I know how to make managed package, but not sure what is needed to make it certified.

Do I must have LMA application and link the package to production org? In such case the issue is that our production is also professional edition and I'm not sure LMA app can be install in such org.

Alternatively, can I use developer free edition to hold the LMA and link to it the org with the package?

Do I need also to go thru the security review step?
Publish in appexchage?
Does certified manage package can still be free?

Comment: I would *assume* this means a managed packaged that has been through the process to have it listed on the AppExchange, and thus through a Security Review. You certainly can find free apps on the AppExchange, but I can say that partners certainly have to pay for Salesforce's security review effort and have to submit a business plan etc. too.

Comment: It does not have to be listed in the appexchange. Understood that there is fee for security review but main question is how/if this process can be done if our production org is professional edition

Comment: Sorry, to be clear I didn't mean you had to have a public listing, but that you must go through the actions required to be able to list. Anyway, David Reed has answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I must have LMA application and link the package to production org? In such case the issue is that our production is also professional edition and I'm not sure LMA app can be install in such org.

I don't believe you need the LMA application. You can submit for Security Review without linking your package to an LMA. (You may *want* its features, however).

> Do I need also to go thru the security review step?

[Yes, you do](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm). Note, the linked document also calls out that you need to be registered as an eligible Salesforce partner to get your package Certified. I don't know the exact details of the partner status required. Salesforce Partner Support may be able to help there, or the Partner Community discussion forum.

Note that there are [other limitations of Professional Edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_for_pe_ge.htm) that your app must be aware of.

> Publish in appexchage?

You will need an AppExchange listing to submit for Security Review, but you can keep it private (unlisted).

> Does certified manage package can still be free?

Yes, it can be free.

Comment: Thanks, I will read further the limitation in professional. I know it is good to have the LMA, but from the documentation I saw it is not available in PE.